# Summing $\sum{\frac{1}{a^{P(n)}}}$ where $P$ is a given polynomial.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the sum: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{P(n)}}$$ converges what is known about the value it converges to (if $a$ and $P(n)$ are known)? I am not sure if even the simple quadratic case can be solved.

Comment: The case $P(n) = n^2$ gives you $(\theta_3(0,1/a) - 1)/2$, where $\theta_3$ is a Jacobi theta function.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. How is that derived can you give a link?

Comment: Wait, isn't that by definition?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for $P(n) = n^2$, 
$$  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a^{n^2}} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \theta_3\left( 0 , \frac{1}{a} \right) -1 \right)  \text{,}  $$
where $\theta_3$ is the third Jacobi theta function.  (See (10) at [MathWorld: Jacobi Theta Functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).)  It's only convergent for $\frac{1}{a}$ in the (complex) unit disk.

In the following, I have assumed that $P(n) \in \mathbb{Z}[n]$, that is the set of polynomials in $n$ with integer coefficients.  If the intened polynomials take non-integer values for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, this question becomes much more complicated.  (See [Robert Israel's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417166/summing-sum-frac1apn-where-p-is-a-given-polynomial/2417187?noredirect=1#comment4993807_2417187) for a sampler.)

I don't have a reference, but I suspect "many" quadratic $P(n)$ can be handled by a little ingenuity with the four theta functions.

Regarding convergence ...

Since $P(n)$ of degree $\geq 2$ eventually grows aperiodically, it is not rational, so has the unit circle as a natural boundary.  See Bell et al. (Bell, Jason P., Nils Bruin, and Michael Coons, "Transcendence of Generating Functions Whose Coefficients are Multiplicative", https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.2221.pdf ) to get a start into the literature.  Their Theorem 1.2:

> **Theorem 1.2** (Carlson [10])**.**  A series $F(z) = \sum_{n \geq 1} f(n) z^n \in \mathbb{Z}[[z]]$ that converges inside the unit disk is either rational or it admits the unit circle as a natural boundary.

In your variables, $z = 1/a$, and $f(n) = \begin{cases}1, &n \in \{P(k) \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\} \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}  \end{cases}$.  A rational function eventually has periodic $f$, but the gaps between values of $P(k)$ grow without bound.  Consequently, if $\deg P \geq 2$, your series only converges for $1/a$ on the unit disk.  That is, it only converges for $a$ outside the unit disk.  It can't even be analytically continued into the disk.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n^2+bn+c}$ is an incomplete theta function. The complete one is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2+bn+c} = q^c\vartheta(q, e^{2i \pi \tau} = q^c)$

Comment: @reuns : That would be useful to put in an answer...

Comment: @reuns : I made no such assertion.

Comment: There are additional complications if $P$ is not integer-valued: you have to worry about branches, and it's not analytic at $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : You're right.  I seem to have (inappropiately) assumed the OP's polynomials were in $\mathbb{Z}[n]$.  I'll add a short preface.

Comment: do you understand what I wrote ?

Comment: @reuns : Why are you unwilling to submit an answer with your information in it?